# objects array data in asp.net mvc is always null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I need to send an array of objects to asp.net mvc 2 through json, but i am not getting null in the mvc controller

The object is like this

```
entries[1].date = "12/22/2014"
entries[1].Ref = "0002"
entries[1].Credit = "100"

entries[2].date = "12/22/2014"
entries[2].Ref = "0002"
entries[2].Credit = "150"
```

later before send, i do this

```
JSON.stringify(entries)
```

My data in Json looks like this

```
[{"date":"12/22/2014","RefNo":"0002","Credit":"100"},{"date":"12/22/2014","RefNo":"0002","Credit":"150"}]
```

my controller in asp.net method looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MyDataModel[] entries)
{

}
```

and my jquery send code

```
 $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
      type: 'post', // GET or POST
        url: url, // the file to call
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(entries), // get the form da
})
```

The MyDataModel is a model class with the properties of the entries

**More data**

```
 public class MyDataModel
{

    public string Date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "RefNo is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "RefNo Must be Under 40 characters long", MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string RefNo { get; set; }

    // Credit
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Credit is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Range(typeof(Decimal), "1", "999999999999", ErrorMessage = "Credit Must be a number and non zero")]
    public decimal? Credit { get; set; }

}
```

But the entries is always null, why?

Comment: I think `MyDataModel[] entries` should be `String entries` because you send a json string.

Comment: @SinaSadrzadeh: No; the model binder can parse JSON.

Comment: Can we see `MyDataModel`.

Comment: Can you get the JSON string that is sent to the server? You could use the browser dev tools, or Fiddler, to get that data. Being able to see the JSON could help us figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: On the c# side, what serializer are you using - Json.NET, `DataContractJsonSerializer` or `JavaScriptSerializer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON looks incorrect after stringify?

```
[
{"date":"12/22/2014","RefNo":"0002","Credit":"100"},
{"date":"12/22/2014","RefNo":"0002","Credit":"150"
```

]

Missing closing brace..maybe a typo in question only but thought I'd let you know, may help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
      type: 'post', // GET or POST
        url: url, // the file to call
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // Include ContentType
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(entries), // get the form da
})
```

You have to include contentType and It will work after that.

Comment: i am currently using this `$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        type: 'post', // GET or POST
        url: url, // the file to call
        traditional: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: data, // get the form data
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
     });`, which is not also working

Comment: Try to do data : JSON.strigify(entries)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to include the contentType to the ajax call and if that does not work, you could try this way: 
`data: JSON.stringify({"entries" : entries})`

where the entries in quotes is the parameter on the controller and the entries without quotes is your object. And in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(List<MyDatAModel> entries)
{

}
```

You are posting a complex object, so a list of your model will receive your array and add all the elements.

UPDATE
Try this form (this is an example of many ajax request I use) maybe it could help.

```
           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
                data: JSON.stringify(arrayJavascript),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function () {
                  //code...
                }
           });
```

Comment: I tried the `List<MyDataModel>` too, but it still does not work

Comment: i already did what you added to the update too, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/27606097/362461

Comment: well the last thing that comes to my mind is the cache option in the ajax, in your comment you are not using cache, give it a try

Answer (score 0):

change

```
data: JSON.stringify(entries), // get the form da
```

to

```
data: { entries : entries },
```